# Step by Step guide to tomcat web application loading

Tags: spring, tomcat, web-applications

I have a Dynamic web application with Spring security support. I would like to know what steps are followed on a tomcat server to run my application. Like I would like to know when filters are loaded, when listeners are invoked, how and when all the configuration are loaded, what all Objects were loaded by JVM. I have tried to search for a book or reference blog to get sequence of the steps that are followed by a webserver to load my application and run it.

I would like to know all these details just to understand the web application internals. I am using tomcat 7.0.

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: One of the really nice things about Open Source software like Tomcat ... is that you can look at the source code.  Q: Have you installed the Tomcat source?  Q: Have you tried to read it?

Comment: Go here:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/building.html

Comment: I suggest taking one of spring security example applications, set the root logging value in log4j to DEBUG, then deploy it in Tomcat, and review the logs to see when the filters and such are set up and executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the servlet specification. I know it sounds like I'm saying RTFM and referring you to some dense technical manual that nobody in their right mind would read, but the Java Servlet Specification is actually short, succinct, and quite readable.

Unfortunately, you have to download it from Oracle but it's easy enough to get:
http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/index.html

The servlet spec explains how everything works from when filters and listeners are instantiated and invoked, etc. to how container-managed authentication and authorization are required to operate. I consider it required reading for anyone who writes web-based applications.

Comment: I won't mind going deep into technical Stuff. This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks Chris